# Angular 2.0 RC-1 working example of router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Can anyone please provide a working example of Angular 2.0 RC-1 router. Mainly i am looking for example of following..

```
router.navigate(['/testcomponent'])
```

Comment: This should work, as you can see in günter's plunker. Can you provide your `Routes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are wrong. It should be:

```
router.navigate(['/testcomponent'])
```

`router.navigate()` expects an array of path segments (string) and parameters (object). Your example passes a string that contains square brackets. I assume this comes from

```
<a [routerLink]="['/testcomponent']">somewhere</a>
```

where the whole expression is set in quotes but also here the path segment needs to be a string and therefore needs the quotes.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NgkrbG3bilqc91dXxWOC?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I am using the correct syntax.